# how can i access the values of an other script without getting this error: CS0120:An object reference is required for the non-static field?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to access the script ChangeCamera from the script Conrol. I want to acces the value of front_depth which i removed from update function defined like this:

```
float front_depth = 0.5f;
void Update () {
                  //something
               }

 //in  the control script i did:
class Control : MonoBehaviour
  {  
    myMainCamera.GetComponent<ChangeCamera>();
    ChangeCamera.front_depth; 
   }
```

but i got the error error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ChangeCamera.front_depth'

Comment: Define it like `public float front_depth = 0.5f;`, yet in a long term it's not good style of programming

Comment: Show your code please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant access non static variables without an instance (Object Reference), to do so you have to store the instance in a variable, "var" will decide what kind of object for you, then you access the public field **from the variable just created**.

```
var component = myMainCamera.GetComponent<ChangeCamera>();
component.front_depth;
```

and on the other script you need to place the place your variable outside the update method and make it public, you can place it on the start of the class.

```
class ChangeCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float front_depth = 0.5f;
    
    void Update()
    ...
 }
```

***otherwise***

you can just make the variable **static** and access it without an instance of the class.

```
class ChangeCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float front_depth = 0.5f;
    
    void Update()
    ...
 }
```

this way on the other script you would need only this code

```
 ChangeCamera.front_depth = 0.5f;
```

in this case if you have only one camera its probably the sensible choice but if you share your code it would be so much more easy for anyone to help you.

PS: just remember that you cant use variables created on methods out side of them. just like you cant use private variables outside of the class.

Comment: The OP mentioned that their front_depth value is defined in the Update() function, so it is important to specify that the public variable should be class level.

Comment: thanks, didnt realize that, its edited, i cant comment on your answer, but i was wondering you say he can access the ChangeCamera like he wrote but its not a static variable.. or am i missing something?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize he didn't have the class instance cached. I thought OP was just making a mistake by capitalizing a variable and was trying to look past it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your ChangeCamera script looks something like this:

```
public class ChangeCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        float front_depth = 0.5f;
        //... other code
    }
}
```

If that variable needs to be accessed from outside the Update() method, it's a good idea to define that variable at a higher level. Like this:

```
public class ChangeCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    float front_depth = 0.5f;
    void Update()
    {
        //... other code
    }
}
```

The variable is still accessible inside of the Update method, but front_depth is stored at the Class-level, so it can be made accessible to other scripts through a separate method, getters/setters, or by making it public.

The simplest way to make it accessible to external scripts is to make it public:

```
public class ChangeCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float front_depth = 0.5f;
    void Update()
    {
        //... other code
    }
}
```

With the public variable, you can access the variable from other scripts the same way you've written above:

```
myMainCamera.GetComponent<ChangeCamera>();
ChangeCamera.front_depth;
```

You can read/write to a public variable, so this will allow you to change it, or store its value in another variable:

```
ChangeCamera.front_depth = 1.0f; //Changing the front_depth from an external script
float cachedDepth = ChangeCamera.front_depth; //Caching (storing) the front_depth value in a separate variable.
```

For simple variables, this is usually good enough. For complex systems it can be beneficial (and considered best practice) to wrap variables as properties. Properties allow you to have fine control over how much access external scripts have over local variables.

```
public class ChangeCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float front_depth = 0.5f; //You don't need to specify it as private, but I like to anyways
    // Front_Depth is a property that provides access to front_depth in a controlled manner
    public float Front_Depth
    {
       //property READ function
       get 
       {
           return front_depth;
       }
       //property WRITE function
       set
       {
           front_depth = value;
       }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        //... other code
    }
}
```

You can now access that variable externally, which acts the same:

```
ChangeCamera.Front_Depth;
```

**What is the benefit of using a property instead of just making it public?** Well, you can prevent write access to the variable while providing read access by deleting the *set* function. You can also add additional logic to the get/set functions to perform extra stepswhen reading or writing to the variable (like saving the game whenever the score updates, or writing to a log).

Comment: Thank you for your responses all, i tried all the solutions but i got the same erroe which is :      error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ChangeCamera.front_depth' and an other : error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. wheni tried the solution of @Barreto Freekhealer var component = myMainCamera.GetComponent<ChangeCamera>();
component.front_depth i gotjust the second error. I don't understand where the mistake is